# How to pull the index from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to pull the first Index value after each time I sort the dataframe based on values as a string.

And what I want my function to do is pull the country name at the top of the list. In this example, it would pull 'United States' as a string. Because the country names are the indexes and not Series values I can't just do summer_gold.iloc[0].

## Summer    Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total   # Winter    Gold.1  Silver.1    Bronze.1    Total.1 # Games Gold.2  Silver.2    Bronze.2    Combined total  ID

Afghanistan 13  0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   13  0   0   2   2   AFG
Algeria 12  5   2   8   15  3   0   0   0   0   15  5   2   8   15  ALG
Argentina   23  18  24  28  70  18  0   0   0   0   41  18  24  28  70  ARG
Armenia 5   1   2   9   12  6   0   0   0   0   11  1   2   9   12  ARM
Australasia 2   3   4   5   12  0   0   0   0   0   2   3   4   5   12  ANZ

> So if I were to sort based on number of Gold medals I'd get a
>   dataframe that looks like:

```
          # Summer  Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total  # Winter  Gold.1  \
```

United States        26   976     757     666   2399        22      96
Soviet Union          9   395     319     296   1010         9      78
Great Britain        27   236     272     272    780        22      10
France               27   202     223     246    671        22      31
China                 9   201     146     126    473        10      12

```
           Silver.1  Bronze.1  Total.1  # Games  Gold.2  Silver.2  \
```

United States       102        84      282       48    1072       859
Soviet Union         57        59      194       18     473       376
Great Britain         4        12       26       49     246       276
France               31        47      109       49     233       254
China                22        19       53       19     213       168

```
           Bronze.2  Combined total   ID
```

United States       750            2681  USA
Soviet Union        355            1204  URS
Great Britain       284             806  GBR
France              293             780  FRA
China               145             526  CHN

> So far my overall code looks like:

def answer_one():

    summer_gold = df.sort_values('Gold', ascending=False)  

    summer_gold = summer_gold.iloc[0]

    return summer_gold

answer_one()

Output: 

# Summer            26
Gold               976
Silver             757
Bronze             666
Total             2399
# Winter            22
Gold.1              96
Silver.1           102
Bronze.1            84
Total.1            282
# Games             48
Gold.2            1072
Silver.2           859
Bronze.2           750
Combined total    2681
ID                 USA
Name: United States, dtype: object

I want an output of 'United States', in this case, or the name of whatever the country is at the top of my sorted dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

After you `sorted` your `dataframe`, you can access the first row `index` like:

```
df.index[0]
```